# What is the best way to convert ticks to degrees for PWM phase shift (STM32)?

Tags: math, signals, stm32, pwm

**Goal:** implementing a phase shift between PWM TIM1 and TIM8 (STM32F303CBT6).

**How will I do this:**

I will configure TIM1/TIM8 as MASTER/SLAVE and change the phase shift between them.

```
TIM_SetCounter(TIM1, 0); // 0° phase shift
TIM_SetCounter(TIM1, 72); // 180° phase shift
```

[image]

**What I encountered:**

I want to convert the phase shift from degrees to the number of ticks, which I will write to TIM_SetCounter. (0..72 ticks = 0..180°)

[image]

Where f = 100 kHz is the PWM frequency. Period = 10 µs, half-cycle 5 µs.

72 ticks is half a period (100 kHz), the entire period is 144 ticks. (based on TIM1/TIM8 timer settings). It turns out that the time delay will be in the range from 0 to 5 µs.

I have compiled the following formulas to calculate the phase shift:

```
 int degPhaseShiftCalc(int tdelay) {
   int phShift = (360 * 100 * tdelay) / 1000;
   return phShift;
 }

 int tDelayCalc(int phShift) {
   float tdelay = (phShift * 1000) / (360 * 100);
   int result = round(tdelay / 0.07);
   return result;
 }
```

Where 0.07 is the number microseconds per 1 tick. (5us/72ticks)
I used rounding because the system only accepts whole numbers of ticks.

**Calculation results:**

1. 180° = 71 ticks (<72)
2. 150° = 57 ticks
3. 36° = 14 ticks
4. 0..35° = 0 ticks (???)

With a small phase shift, I have an output of 0 ticks in the range of 0..35 degrees.
I can assume that this is due to the small number of ticks per half period and you need to change the timer settings so that the number is > 72.

**Question:** What is the best way to implement the function of converting degrees to ticks?

**SOLVED**
Thank you @Simon Goater, @Chris_B

```
float tdelay = ((float)phShift * 1000.0) / (360.0 * 100.0);
```

Converting to float solved the problem.

Comment: Maybe integer division bug? Try casting to float before dividing by an integer.

Comment: yes, looks like - as Simon already said - as a integer division "bug". Calculate all in float before making one final cast to integer (tics). If your period does not change you can calculate a factor once and replace all the divisions by one factor, so your final function would look like float ftics = float angle * float conversion-factor; int tics = ceil(ftics);

Comment: SimonGoater, Chris_B, Thanks for answers! I will check it.

Comment: Converting to float actually solved the problem. Thank you! I have a variable phase shift. Therefore, an option is to recalculate all values ​​in advance (for each angle) and write them into an array.

Comment: Slight overkill in casting to float, you don't need both the cast and multiplication by a float. `float tdelay = (phShift * 1000.0) / (360.0 * 100.0);` would do.